# Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array like

```
result = np.array([[[289, 354, 331],
                    [291, 206,  66],
                    [242,  70, 256]],

                   [[210, 389, 342],
                    [273, 454, 218],
                    [255,  87, 256]],

                   [[127, 342, 173],
                    [450, 395, 147],
                    [223, 228, 401]]])
```

and i'm trying to mask the array if an element is greater than 255. i.e i assume it to be of range 0-1024 and divide my value by 4

```
result = np.putmask(result, result > 255, result/4)
```

NOTE: result is the previous 3D array.And i'm getting this error

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

What am i doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Explanation of Error:**

This is illustrative of an interesting property of numpy arrays: *all elements of a numpy array must be of the same type*

For instance if you have the following array:

```
>>> array1 = np.array([[23, 632, 634],[23.5, 67, 123.6]])
>>> array1
array([[  23. ,  632. ,  634. ],
   [  23.5,   67. ,  123.6]])
>>> type(array1[0][0])
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

We notice that even though all the elements in the list [23, 632, 634] were all of the type *int* (specifically *'numpy.int64'*), all of the elements in *array1* were converted to floats because of the element *123.6* in the second row (notice the decimal points in the array print out).

Similarily, if we include even one string anywhere in the array, all the elements of the array are cast to strings:

```
>>> array2 = np.array([[23, 632, 'foo'],[23.5, 67, 123.6]])
>>> type(array2[0][0])
<class 'numpy.str_'>
```

**Conclusion:**

Your original *result* array contains elements of type *'numpy.int64'*, but the `result/4` operation returns an array of elements of type *'numpy.float64'* (since *82 / 4 = 20.5*, etc.).  Thus when you try and replace the values in *result*, it is not 'safe' as you are inadvertently trying to place floats into an array of ints.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you divide by 4, you are creating float values, which don't want to go into the array of `int`s.

If you want to use `putmask`, and avoid the problem of trying to convert to float, then you can use floor division (`//`) in order to change your values to `int`:

```
np.putmask(result, result>255, result//4)

>>> result
array([[[ 72,  88,  82],
        [ 72, 206,  66],
        [242,  70,  64]],

       [[210,  97,  85],
        [ 68, 113, 218],
        [255,  87,  64]],

       [[127,  85, 173],
        [112,  98, 147],
        [223, 228, 100]]])
```

## Alternative #1:

Convert your `result` array to a float `dtype`, and use your original `putmask`:

```
result = result.astype(float)

np.putmask(result, result > 255, result/4)

>>> result
array([[[ 72.25,  88.5 ,  82.75],
        [ 72.75, 206.  ,  66.  ],
        [242.  ,  70.  ,  64.  ]],

       [[210.  ,  97.25,  85.5 ],
        [ 68.25, 113.5 , 218.  ],
        [255.  ,  87.  ,  64.  ]],

       [[127.  ,  85.5 , 173.  ],
        [112.5 ,  98.75, 147.  ],
        [223.  , 228.  , 100.25]]])
```

You can even convert back to int after if desired:

```
result = result.astype(int)

array([[[ 72,  88,  82],
        [ 72, 206,  66],
        [242,  70,  64]],

       [[210,  97,  85],
        [ 68, 113, 218],
        [255,  87,  64]],

       [[127,  85, 173],
        [112,  98, 147],
        [223, 228, 100]]])
```

## Alternative #2:

Do away with `putmask` altogether, and you can get your desired results like this:

```
result[result > 255] = result[result > 255] / 4

>>> result
array([[[ 72,  88,  82],
        [ 72, 206,  66],
        [242,  70,  64]],

       [[210,  97,  85],
        [ 68, 113, 218],
        [255,  87,  64]],

       [[127,  85, 173],
        [112,  98, 147],
        [223, 228, 100]]])
```

Comment: Yep. That worked thanks. But any way how to solve the problem I had?

Comment: See the first method I suggested (in my edited post), I tried to explain what was happening.